SQL join with missing data
I have two tables, NAME and ADDRESS. For both tables, the primary key is ID and Language. I want to join these two tables on ID and Language, but sometimes there will be a case where the address table does not have a matching language for the ID, but there is a matching entry with a language set to English.
How can I get the join to return the matching language entry, or the English entry if there is no matching language?
I.e,



ID
Language
Name




A
ENG
Fred


A
CYM
Dref


B
ENG
Cane


B
CYM
Zark






ID
Language
Addr




A
ENG
Ad1


A
CYM
Ad2


B
ENG
Ad3



if I do
select Name, Addr
from NAME
inner join ADDR on NAME.ID = ADDR.ID
               and NAME.Language = ADDR.Language

I get



Name
Addr




Fred
Ad1


Dref
Ad2


Cane
Ad3



if I do
select Name, Addr
from NAME
left join ADDR on NAME.ID = ADDR.ID
              and NAME.Language = ADDR.Language

I get



Name
Addr




Fred
Ad1


Dref
Ad2


Came
Ad3


Zark
null



How do I get



Name
Addr




Fred
Ad1


Dref
Ad2


Came
Ad3


Zark
Ad3



This for both MSSQL and Postgres RDBMS systems.

What RDBMS do you use?

@JonasMetzler This is for both MSSQL and Postgres.

here is one way :
with cte as (
  select t1.* 
  , t2.Addr 
  , row_number() over (partition by t1.ID, t1.language order by case when t1.language = t2.language then 0 else 1 end) rn
from t1
join t2 on t1.ID = t2.ID 
)
select * from cte where rn = 1

output :



id
language
name
addr
rn




A
CYM
Dref
Ad2
1


A
ENG
Fred
Ad1
1


B
CYM
Zark
Ad3
1


B
ENG
Cane
Ad3
1




The way I see it from what you posted, you can't. Or only by chance.
I understand that you expect Fred, Dref, Cane, and Mark to appear in the report of the joining query in the same order as they seem to be in the name table, so that you can copy the previous value, 'Ad3' into the NULL that would appear for 'Zark'.
According to the SQL standard, relational tables are not ordered. It is perfectly correct if one SELECT * FROM name returns Fred, Dref, Cane, Mark, and the next exactly same query returns Cane, Dref, Zark, Fred.
So you're stuck here.
If you enrich your name table by a sorting criterion, say an integer column seq , you can apply OLAP/window functions like LAG() or LAST_VALUE() IGNORE NULLS in case of many consecutive missing addresses,  to get the previous row's value or the last known value according to the sort order.

see my answer, it's possible easily

Clever, @eshirvana2, but very probably pure chance, though, in that data cutout we got, I think....

It's easy to replace the "missing" addresses with the english one, but it's still unclear how to enforce the exact order of rows. The question doesn't tell us if the sort is important at all.

I'm not expecting any particular order in the output, I've been bitten by that too many times, it was just the way I copied the tables..

@marcothesane what do you mean pure chance? It's logic not chance ;)
